# Linq to SQL with medium trust level

Tags: asp.net, linq, medium-trust

I used Linq to SQL in an ASP.NET app that I now need to deploy on a server. Unfortunately, the hosting sever can only offer a medium level trust. My app crashes not having permission of type ReflectionPermission.

Is there a way to edit my queries to work around this restriction?

For example, my app crashes when calling this code:

```
Error error = new Error { Date = DateTime.Now, Message = message, StackTrace = stack };
dataContext.Errors.InsertOnSubmit(error);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may yield some insight: http://davedewinter.com/2009/04/22/using-linq-to-sql-and-ef-in-sharepoint-under-medium-trust/

Comment: Althought that may be a solution, I don't have access to the machine web config, this being a shared hosting server.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by your `ReflectionPermission.RestrictedMemberAccess` property.

Make sure that your every property in the EF model classes is public.

I had a more complicated problem, though might be similar to your case.
I've aggregated a class in my EF model class which had private properties. 
During loading, any record from DB, EF also tries to load every property from this aggregated class.

Removing this reference from one of my model classes (and replacing it by copying needed properties) resolved the problem in the medium trust environment.